# SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to android.text.SpannableString

Tags: java, android, html

I need to save data from `TextView` to and SQLite database in HTML format.

I'm using this code to convert text from `TextView` to HTML-formatted string:

```
public static String htmlToString(TextView textview) {
SpannableString contentText = (SpannableString) textview.getText();
return Html.toHtml(contentText).toString();
}
```

However, I get this error:

> 05-05 17:01:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(14295):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
>   cannot be cast to android.text.SpannableString

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Public Constractor

```
SpannableString(CharSequence source)
```

so just do

```
public static String htmlToString(TextView textview) {
SpannableString contentText = new SpannableString(textview.getText());
return Html.toHtml(contentText).toString();
}
```